# Manually initiate time sync in PainlessMesh

Tags: esp32, mesh-networks

I'm using Expressif ESP32 dev boards and the PainlessMesh library.  My nodes do an initial time sync, but after a while I've seen odd behavior where the calculated offset is negative... implying that the message came from the future.

I see in the [PainlessMesh class definition](https://painlessmesh.gitlab.io/painlessMesh/classpainlessMesh.html) a protected method called startTimeSync, which sounds similar to what I want.  Is there a way to manually initiate a time sync request via PainlessMesh?

Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that I did see the mesh protocol time sync explanation, which is helpful for understanding what's happening behind the scenes, I just want to kick it off... https://gitlab.com/painlessMesh/painlessMesh/wikis/mesh-protocol#time-sync

Answer (score 1):

Had a conversation with the folks over at Painlessmesh.  There is a way, but it's not meant to be invoked directly:

https://gitlab.com/painlessMesh/painlessMesh/issues/276

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be much better if you could include the essential parts of the linked page with the link for reference.  Thanks!